# Create a Class with full name and pass it to the custom component

Tags: apache-flex

I have class name : some.path.exampleclass and have to instantiate class (like getDefinitionByName()). Problem is that getDefinitionByName() makes class exampleclass and i need class with FULL name : some.path.exampleclass to pass it to custom component :

```
<tools:MyComp value="some.path.exampleclass"/>
```

Is there a quick solution for this? :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're looking for a solution to.  You may want to try to re-write your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Form HTTPservice I get something like: <url>assets.some.class</url>. Then I do something like this: var clazz:Class = getDefintionByName(data.url) as Class; in itemRenderer... Next, I have to pass clazz to component but with full path "assets.some.class" and getDefinitionByName gives me only "class".

Comment: Or, to be more specific, I have to pass FXG image class to component which displays it. Setter method of that component need to be set with full path class not only with one that getDefinitionByName gives me...

Answer (score 0):

If you're intent is to create an instance of an FXG element based on a string that represents it's fully qualified class name, you can do it like this:

```
var classNameString :String = // your code to get the classname;
var class :Class = getDefinitionByName( className ) as Class;
var newObject : MyObject = new class() as MyObject;
```

This should work perfectly fine with FXG Elements.  I use it in my mobile game.

You mention that:

> Setter method...need to be set with full path class
>   not only with one that getDefinitionByName gives me

getDefinitionByName returns an instance of Class.  If your method is expecting a string that is why getDefinitionByName doesn't work.

For more specifics, if needed, you should provide the full source code for the method or property.